# How i configure my apache to enable email sent in php?

Tags: php, apache, email, configuration, system-administration

Maybe is a stupid question... but i need to configure my apache+php to send emails via PHP? i have to set a domain to it? the domain has to be configured via DNS?

any lights here please ^^

TIA.

Comment: apache is HTTP server, not MTA. you cannot configure it to send emails

Comment: i mean to send mails via PHP scripts (i have some websites programmed in php that sends mails... i replicated the website on another server but the problems dosnt send mails anymore... everything works perfect, but not mail send)

Comment: Apache doesn't do that. You need a mail server. What OS are you on?

Comment: I imagine he's trying to use the mail() function.  Which by default uses sendmail

Answer (score 2):

Look in your phpinfo() and see what your sendmail path is.  Try sending mail from the command line using whatever that path points to.  If it doesn't work, you need to start there.

Comment: What if I'm running php on Windows?  (Looks like sendmail is only used for unix/linux.)

Comment: Do a google search for sendmail alternatives for windows.  Mail servers are not one of windows strong points.  If this is just a development server, in your house, you might also have trouble sending mail if you're using a residential ISP.